# Como fazer uma consulta no mysql usando ignore index com group_concat?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma query que faz o `inner join` de tabelas pesadas com o filtro `where coluna = 'valor da coluna'`, roda até que razoável mas precisaria rodar esse query sem o filtro. Só que a query carregava até perder a conexão com servidor.
Pesquisando, achei uma função `ignore index` e `use index`, com o `ignore index`, conseguir pelo menos trazer as informações, apesar de ainda esta demorando um pouco mas até ai tudo bem.
Meu problema agora é que nessa query, preciso fazer um `group_concat` com duas colunas, a query volta a carregar sem parar. Sem esse `group_concat` roda normal.

Alguém sabe uma maneira de fazer a query rodar com o `ignore index` e o `group_concat`?

Minha query é mais ou menos assim:

```
select 
coluna1,
coluna2,
group_concat(distinct(concat(subject_id,',',subject_value)), '') as valor,
coluna 3,
time_update
from
tabela1 as a straight_join tabela2 as b on a.columa1 = b.coluna2 
straight_join tabela3 as c on b.coluna2 = c.coluna3 where 
date_format(c.time_update,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date_format(date_add(curdate(), interval -3 day), '%Y-%m-%d');
```